# check if second to last in an iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Is there a clean way to check if I am currently at the second to last element in an iteration in C++? As in:

```
for (vector::iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); ++it)
{
   if (it points to second to last element)
      cout << "at second to last";
}
```

Comment: Checking the position of the iterator makes more sense on bidirectional iterators and forward iterators. For random access iterator, you might as well just use the index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to compare your iterator against one which does indeed point to the second-to-last.  And an easy way to get that is:

```
vector::iterator secondLast = v.end() - 2;
```

Assuming of course that `v.size() >= 2`.  But the above doesn't generalize to other container types, for which you could do this:

```
vector::iterator secondLast = (++v.rbegin()).base();
```

This should rewind from the last element one step, then convert to a regular (forward) iterator.  This will work with other container types like lists.

Or perhaps clearer for the general solution:

```
vector::iterator secondLast = v.end();
std::advance(secondLast, -2);
```

Again this requires size of 2 and iterators of random access or bidirectional type.

And finally, a C++11 solution:

```
auto secondLast = std::prev(v.end(), 2);
```

Comment: `std::prev(v.end(), 2)` can also be used.

Comment: @0x499602D2, not for `forward_iterator`s, only for bi-directional, same for `std::advance`

Comment: @vsoftco: none of the solutions I posted work for pure forward iterators either.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry, I just saw your last line now. I guess one cannot do better than `O(n)` for the most general iterator, but your solution  is definitely elegant for bidirectional ones.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, `std::advance` takes a reference to an iterator then advances it, and returns `void`. You probably meant `std::prev(v.end(), -2)`, or `std::advance(secondLast, -2)`, where `secondLast` was previously initialized to `v.end()`

Comment: Just to say, don't forget the type, e.g. long.  Thus I used this:

`std::vector<long>::iterator secondLast = v.end();
std::advance(secondLast, -2);`

Answer (score 1):

A solution below:

```
auto pos = std::next(std::begin(v), std::distance(std::begin(v), std::end(v))-2);
for (auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v); ++it)
{
   if (it == pos)
      cout << "at second to last: " << *pos;
}
```

`pos` is now an iterator pointing to the second to last position, and the functions `std::next` and `std::distance` use the best implementation possible (i.e. constant complexity for random iterators, linear complexity for bidirectional/forward iterators).

Comment: `end()` returns an iterator after the last element, so `end-1` would be the last element, and `end-2` would be the send-to-last element.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, absolutely correct, I modified it, thanks for catching it.

Comment: This is not the most efficient solution for forward or bidirectional iterators.  Imagine using it with a list: first you iterate over the entire list for `distance`, then again for `next`, before you get on with the actual work.  Optimal for bidirectional is O(1) not O(n), and for forward iterators optimal is single-pass (with constant space), not two-pass.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, hmm, you're right, forgot about the the complexity of distance. I guess the previous solution (which I managed to delete) was better. `O(1)` is for random iterators (not bidirectional), that's what you mean, right?

Comment: @vsoftco: no, O(1) for bidirectional, because you start from the end and go backward two, as seen in my answer (which doesn't support forward-only iterators--those are still O(n) of course).

Comment: @JohnZwinck, ahh ok I thought you are talking in general, for an arbitrary element.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
vector::iterator end = v.end(), stl;
bool has_stl = (v.size() >= 2);
if (has_stl) stl = end-2;

for (vector::iterator it = v.begin(); it < end; ++it)
{
   if ((has_stl) && (it == stl))
      cout << "at second to last";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some containers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
        if (vec.end() - it == 3) {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```